Proof of L'Hospital being appliable to $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty } \frac{z^2+e^{4z}}{2z-e^{z}}$?
I was following paul's online notes and I came across this practice problem:
$\lim\limits_{z \to \infty } \frac{z^2+e^{4z}}{2z-e^{z}}$
It says that when we plug in the limit leads to
$\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$
So we can apply the L'Hospital rule
Isn't the denominator equal to $\infty-\infty$ when we plug the values?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean all $x$ or all $z$?

To apply L'Hospital's Rule, it is NOT required that the numerator goes to infinity.  In fact, the numerator need not even have a limit provided that the denominator tends to infinity.

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } {2x-e^{x}} = -\infty$ since $e^x>(2x)^2$ for $x>e^2$

Don't plug in: think about what is going on. For large $x$, $e^x$ massively dominates the growth of $2x$. For any polynomial $f(x)$, $(e^x + f(x))/e^x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. It is irrelevant what the coefficients in $f(x)$ are.

Let the given limit be L
$$\implies L=\lim_{z\to 
\infty}\frac{z^{2}+e^{4z}}{2z-e^{z}}$$
If we plug in $x\to \infty$ in the given limit, then we will get the above limit to be of the form of $\left(\frac{\infty+\infty}{\infty-\infty}\right)$
Now always keep this concept in mind that $(\infty-\infty)\neq 0$
And also L-Hospital's rule is applicable only in case of indeterminate forms.
For this problem $(\infty+\infty)$ is an indeterminate form and also $(\infty-\infty)$ is an indeterminate form.
Generally L-Hospital's rule is Applicable for limits of the functions of the form of $\frac{0}{0}$, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $\left(\frac{\infty+\infty}{\infty-\infty}\right)$, etc.
L-Hospital's rule is not applicable for the limits of the functions of the form of $\frac{0}{\infty},\frac{\infty}{0}$, etc.

Just try it. First the denominator looks like inf minus inf, but that doesn't matter because the right hand side grows much faster, so this isn't the problem.
But if you calculate the limit of f' and g', both are infinity again, so you have the same situation again. Apply l'hospital again, and the same situation again and so on.
Just divide numerator and denominator by $e^z$.

You can avoid the obstacle with the denominator by calculating the limit of the repricocal $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{2x-e^x\over x^2+e^{4x} }$$
Then you can safely apply the l'Hospital rule three times and get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{-e^x\over 4^3e^{4x} }= -4^{-3}\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-3x}=0^{-}$$ Therefore $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x^2+e^{4x}\over 2x-e^x} =-\infty$$

How can $0^-$ be the value of a limit?

@MathGuy It gives informatiin that the function approaches $0$ from the LHS.

But doesn't $0^-$ mean approaching $0$ from the left, i.e., this is not an exact value but rather a notation. Whereas, a limit that exists is a finite quantity.

@MathGuy The value of the limit is $0.$ However if we want to calculate the limit of the reciprocal it is important to know that $0$ is approached through negative values.

Yes, I understand your point, I was just saying that you should've phrased it like $x\to0\implies\displaystyle\frac{2x-e^x}{x^2+e^{4x}}\to0^-$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+e^{4x}}{2x-e^x}=0$.
